# Is there a way to get last form class from the calling stack?

Tags: c#, winforms, types, instance, callstack

I have a custom message box (a winform basically) which pops up on the **center of the calling form**, like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MsgBox.Show(this, "asdsdfsdf");
    }
}
```

Here I pass `this` (Form1) as the owner of `MsgBox`. Now I know where to position the MsgBox form since I am passing the parent form (`Form1`) as well.

But I need this custom messagebox to align itself (center to parent form) even if called from other classes, for eg,

```
public class Computer
{
    public void Do(int i)
    {
        MsgBox.Show(i.ToString());
    }
}
```

The problem here is I can't pass reference of the parent form to `MsgBox` class. So here I wont be able to position the custom box. What I would love to have is an ability for `MsgBox` class to determine which is the last form class in the call stack?

I tried this:

```
public partial class MsgBox : Form
{
    private void X()
    {
        StackTrace df = new StackTrace();
        foreach (var item in df.GetFrames())
        {
            var type = item.GetMethod().DeclaringType;
            if (type.BaseType == typeof(Form))
            {
                IWin32Window w = //how to get the form instance here??
                //------------
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do get upto the inner if clause; the problem is that I dont know how to get the form instance or the IWin32Window handle of the form from the `type` variable.. Is there something I can do to get the **instances** itself of the classes rather than the **types**?

**A Big Edit**: Apologies, that's been a big mistake I made to say that **getting the reference of parent form is to center the child form**. I need parent form's handle in MsqBox instance as it does other things as well. In short I need the parent form in child form without reference of parent not being passed. Is it possible?

Comment: even if there would be a possibility, that would be a very bad programming style ....

Comment: what is a problem with parent reference passing to the dialog ?

Comment: @Tigran There is no problem. The first code block in my question works fine. But the trouble is from the 2nd code block onwards. I cant pass reference of the parent form from non-form classes, say `Computer` in my example, since I am not passing reference of Form1 to Computer. I cant keep passing around Form1 to all internal classes. Instead I would like to have my child itself determining who is his dad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of doing it, thanks @Joe:

```
public static Form GetLastForm()
{
    if (Form.ActiveForm != null && !(Form.ActiveForm is MsgBox))
        return Form.ActiveForm;

    var openForms = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Where(f => !(f is MsgBox));
    if (openForms.Count > 0)
        return openForms[openForms.Count - 1];

    return null;
}
```

I had problem getting the correct parent form thru stack trace approach. Here the basic confusion is to identify if I wanted the current active form, or the last opened form, or the form that caused the MsgBox to pop up. All three can be different, and I went for stack trace approach so as to get third one. Depending on stack trace was frustrating. I just now get the active form, if not I retrieve the last opened form. `Application.OpenForms` have the forms in exact correct order forms were opened.

Comment: Apart from any performance considerations, inlining might mean you don't find what you expect in the StackTrace, especially in a Release build.

Comment: @Joe i do not understand you. I'm currently using this in release build, and I do not find a fault till now. I will consider it once I find issues..

Comment: I do not think the stack trace is really the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

You could try centering your MessageBox on [Form.ActiveForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform.aspx).

Comment: After much reading I realized its not possible to get the instance itself from reflection. Though not an answer, i will accept this..

Comment: @AgentFire why not for my first sentence or 2nd?

Comment: @nawfal Why can not you get the form instance with `Form.ActiveForm`?

Comment: @AgentFire, I can get and that is reflected in my answer too. Joe's answer helped me to reach a workable solution. I just expanded on his idea. In my case, MsgBox itself is a form, and hence Form.ActiveForm can give me a reference to MsgBox which is not what I would ever want. Also Form.ActiveForm will be null if application doesnt have focus. Please read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

- Keep the private `Form Parent { get; private set; }` property in each `MsgBox` class instance.
- Create `MsgBox.ActiveForm { get { .. } }` **static** property which will pick the `Form.ActiveForm` and if it is of type `MsgBox` then return it's parent.

---

Static property of `MsgBox` class:

```
public static Form ActiveForm
{
    get
    {
        return Form.ActiveForm == null ? null :
            Form.ActiveForm is MsgBox ? ((MsgBox)Form.ActiveForm).Parent :
            Form.ActiveForm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Agent, I can not do this. Thats the first part of the question. Message boxes can be popped up from any class. I cant keep passing the form reference all over. Just seeing if there was a better option

Comment: this is good, but then again it will fail when there is no focus on any form. that is why i rely on stack trace.